# Crashlytics Beta build for Android will not install if production build exists: 'The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name'

Tags: android, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

Our team distributes beta build through Crashlytics and most of us have the production build installed on our phones. We aren't able to install the beta build without removing the production app. (Both builds have different applicationId, as in:
    prod: `com.abc`
    beta: `com.abc.beta`)

We tried using the same keystore (as production) and also a different one to sign the beta build, but it doesn't change anything.

Is there a way to install both beta and production builds on the same device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating the issue for some time, and thanks to the help from the Fabric team, I've managed to found the issue and also a way to resolve it.

Using `adb logcat`, I've found the underlying error of the failure:

```
Package attempting to redeclare permission com.abc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE already owned by
```

It appears that the beta app is trying to write to the same permission file that's owned by the production build. To avoid that, I edited my `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

So that the beta app has its own permission folder to write to.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. There is an Apple restriction that only allows Testflight or Mobile Device Manager's from installing an app with the same bundle id, so we're prevented from installing over a version installed from the App Store if the bundle id is the same. For example, you couldn't install a beta production version of the app over the App Store production version.

Comment: thanks for responding but that's no what I'm asking. First of all, we have different bundle ids for production and beta builds, and there is no issue installing both on iOS at the moment. We can't however, do the same on Android. We don't want to install the beta build over prod, just want them to be installed separately on the same device. Any chance this can be achieved?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was OOO. You have different package names and you're unable to install the beta build for Android? That should be fine, so if that's the case, email support(at)fabric(dot)io so we can look at some logs from Logcat when the installation is failing.